# How to Find or Replace New Line Character in ORACLE SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I press Ctrl + F in SQL Developer the Find/Replace tool comes up.  I need to replace a new line with ',' .  I can't figure out how to search for a new line.  In SSMS I could hit Ctrl+F and enter \n in the find or replace field if I wanted to find or replace a new line.  How do I do this with ORACLE SQL Developers Find and Replace tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open Find/Replace, then:

- enter `\n` into the search field
- enter `,` into the replace field
- push the **Regular expresssion** button in the toolbar (it is 4th in my 18.3 version, after Match Case, Whole word, Highlight)
- push the "Replace all" button in the toolbar